# Writing a request JSON for fetchURL in Google Scripts: Script runs twice?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, clockify

sorry in advance for the long question. I am trying to create a Google Sheet that tells me how many hours each of my contractors has logged on Clockify each the month. (Full code at the bottom)

In short my problem is creating a JSON file for the UrlFetchApp.fetch() request to the Clockify API using input from the google sheet.

I want the JSON to look like this:

```
var newJSON = {
        "dateRangeStart": "2022-01-01T00:00:00.000",
        "dateRangeEnd": "2022-01-31T23:59:59.000",
        "summaryFilter": {
          "groups": ["USER"],
          "sortColumn": "GROUP"
        }
      }
var payload = JSON.stringify (newJSON);
```

And when I use this code, it works perfectly. However, the start and end dates are variables that I compute in the google sheet, as I need these dates to change each month. I wrote a function that gives me the correct outputs ("2022-01-01T00:00:00.000", "2022-01-31T23:59:59.000"), but when I reference the cells in google sheets, I get a 400 error saying that the API was not able to parse the JSON.

**Function in Script:**

```
function GetHours(userName, startDate, endDate) {

  var newJSON = {
        "dateRangeStart": startDate,
        "dateRangeEnd": endDate,
        "summaryFilter": {
          "groups": ["USER"],
          "sortColumn": "GROUP"
        }
      }

  var payload = JSON.stringify (newJSON); 
...}
```

**Calling the function in sheets:**

```
=GetHours(C3,$D$45,$D$46)
```

**Output error message:**

Exception: Request failed for https://reports.api.clockify.me returned code 400. Truncated server response: {"code":400,"message":"generateSummaryReport.arg1.dateRangeEnd: Field dateRangeEnd is required, generateSummaryReport.arg1.dateRangeStart: Field da... (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response)

**A weird thing is happening when I use Logger.log(payload), which may be the root of the problem.** It appears that the code runs twice, and the first time the payload JSON is correct, but the second it is incorrect.

*First time:*
{"dateRangeStart":"2022-01-01T00:00:00.000","dateRangeEnd":"2022-01-31T23:59:59.000","summaryFilter":{"groups":["USER"],"sortColumn":"GROUP"}}

*Second time:*
{"summaryFilter":{"groups":["USER"],"sortColumn":"GROUP"}}

I have tried a bunch of solutions, but really it boils down to referencing the Google sheet in the JSON. When I copy and paste the output of my date calculation into the JSON, it works. When I create a variable in Scripts with the date calculation output, it works. When I return startDate, it gives me "2022-01-01T00:00:00.000", which is correct. I just don't understand what is going wrong. Thanks for your help!

**Full code:**

```
const APIbase = "https://api.clockify.me/api/v1"
const APIreportsbase = "https://reports.api.clockify.me/v1"
const myAPIkey =  "[HIDDEN FOR PRIVACY]"
const myWorkspaceID = "[HIDDEN FOR PRIVACY]"

function GetHours(userName, startDate, endDate) {

  var newJSON = {
        "dateRangeStart": startDate,
        "dateRangeEnd": endDate,
        "summaryFilter": {
          "groups": [
            "USER"
          ],
          "sortColumn": "GROUP"
        }
      }

var payload = JSON.stringify (newJSON);
  var headers = {"X-Api-Key" : myAPIkey, "content-type" : "application/json"};
  var url = APIreportsbase + '/workspaces/' + myWorkspaceID + '/reports/summary'

  var options = {
    "method": "post",
    "contentType": "application/json",
    "headers": headers,
    "payload": payload,
    "muteHttpExceptions" : false
  };


  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options)
  var json = response.getContentText();
  var data = JSON.parse(json);
  var people = data.groupOne;


  for (let i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {

    if (people[i].name == userName) {

      if (people[i].duration == 0) {
        return 0;
      } else {
        return people[i].duration/3600;
      }
   } 
  }
}

GetHours();
```

Comment: Since you are only going to run this once a month, why not just make it a standard function that you run from a menu once a month.

Comment: Hi @Cooper Thanks for your quick response. It seems that anything that requires user input gives the same result. I set up an array with all of the start dates and another with the end dates. I have the function take a key that directs it to the correct start/end pair. =GetHours(C3,1) for January. But I get the same error.

Comment: I keep monthly records of this information, so I don't really want to go in and edit the script every month and have it mess up my older records. If that makes sense.

Comment: Sorry, I'm probably not the right person for this question because I never use cell functions.

Comment: From your `Full code:`, if you are directly using the showing script of `Full code:`, I think that `GetHours();` is declared as the global. By this, when the function of `GetHours` is run, the function `GetHours` is run 2 times. I thought that this might be the reason for your issue. So, in this case, please remove the line of `GetHours();` and test it again. But if your `Full code:` is not the actual script and my guess was not correct, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the program working by adding filter so that the second time the program ran, it didn't affect the return value.

```
if (startDate != null) {
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options)
  var json = response.getContentText();
  .....
}
```